# How to make compatibale a css design for all the browsers?

Tags: css

I made a web page with HTML and PHP and design it with CSS. When I open this webpage in Mozill aFirefox, it works as I designed but when I open it in Internet Explorer, the design of page does not according to the settings I designed in CSS file. How to fix it?

Comment: Ask more-specific questions. ***Much*** more specific. Oh, and sleep with http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html under your pillow.

Comment: In my experience, it is not possible to design a web that looks exactly in all the major browsers... Specially with old browser that do not support CSS 3... Unless you write specific code for some browsers

Comment: You could take a look at [Normailze.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

Comment: Complicated question, simple answer: IE, and sometimes other browsers, don't follow standards. You can start here, from the old days: http://www.positioniseverything.net/

Comment: @cacho That may be your experience but it is certainly not true. Of course it depends on the complexity of the design but also depends on how much you wish to rely on pure CSS as opposed to imagery etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by either add CSS to your current css file to correct it. Or make a new css specifically for each browser. That happens because each web browser displays it a little differently. IE that handles CSS and HTML differently more so than all the others.

Answer (score -1):

Cross browser css has been difficult for years! But there is a framework that tries to make it easier.

http://sass-lang.com/ Sass compiles your code and generates cross-browser css. There is a ruby gem that will 'watch' your files for you and generate the css on the fly.
Good Luck!